# What specific technical advantages, if any, for any use-case, does bitcoin have over ether

Tags: ether, bitcoin, use-cases

*Please note:  I have reviewed 
[What advantages and disadvantages does Ethereum have over Bitcoin?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/390/what-advantages-and-disadvantages-does-ethereum-have-over-bitcoin) and 
[What (if anything) in Bitcoin is better than Ether in the application area of a payment system?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/what-if-anything-in-bitcoin-is-better-than-ether-in-the-application-area-of-a) but this question has a very specific, and timely, focus, compared to the first, and the second only considers a specific application scope.*

The 'common' responses, that do not address the technical capabilities, are given in answers to the semi-related questions linked above:

> Where Bitcoin is intended to be a general purpose currency, Ethereum’s Ether (its own internal currency) is used specially to finance the internal processes of Ethereum.

- Please address technology and capability, not intent and original purpose. Please consider both 'general purpose currency' and any other use of Bitcoin.

> the Bitcoin network is stronger than Ethereum because of the network effects of adoption

- Advantages due to 'history-to-date' such as scale, penetration, awareness, and other network-effects etc are not relevant to *this* question.
- The technical advantages of Ethereum over Bitcoin are many, well discussed, and easy to find. They are not pertinent to this question *unless* to help illuminate an advantage of Bitcoin.
- Please consider Bitcoin including SegWit, or dynamic block scaling, or anything else that could be incorporated into Bitcoin (he says without a hint of scepticism) in the foreseeable future.

Please excuse the tight focus here - I've been searching: it's not hard to find people asking the question, but statements like the below are impossible to find amongst the noise.

- Bitcoin has technical advantage *x* over Ether, or
- Bitcoin has *no* technical advantages over Ether

So please don't refrain from saying Ether offers a true super-set of Bitcoin, with no technical-implementation-and-capability disadvantages, if you knowledgeably understand that to be the case. Where Bitcoin has a specific advantage, please give or reference some technical explanation.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/416/what-are-the-critiques-of-ethereum-made-by-bitcoin-experts-and-which-ones-do-no  (I'm also seeking for other solid answers.)